# Existence for elliptic equation with lower order term

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain. I have the nonlinear equation
$$-\Delta u + u + c_0u = f$$
where $c_0:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. I don't have a sign on $c_0$. The data $f \in H^{-1}$.

Is there any chance for existence of solutions to this equation in the usual Sobolev spaces? The equation is linear but I can't apply Lax-Milgram since the $c_0$ term may not yield coercivity of the bilinear form.

Comment: Do you at least know $c_0$ is bounded? Do you have a boundary condition?

Comment: Anyway, you should expect behaviour something like an eigenvalue problem: for "most" $c_0$ there will be unique solutions, but for some special values there will be a finite-dimensional space of solutions. If you're just interested in existence then I think you will have it. See e.g. section 8.2 of Gilbarg & Trudinger.

Comment: For reasonable function $c_0$ (e.g., $c_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, the operator $H_0^1(\Omega) \ni u \mapsto -\Delta u + u + c_0 \, u \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is a Fredholm operator with index zero. Hence, it has a finite-dimensional kernel and a range with finite codimension.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I only have it in $L^2(\Omega)$. We can take 0 BCs. Thanks for the reference.